# Include external project into makefile

Tags: c, git, build, makefile

I have two C projects that I want to use together.  The first one is the git source code.  The second is a different project that has many of the same dependencies as git (namely openssl and curl).  Both of these projects have their own make files and I can build them independently.  Great.  However, I want to be able to call the files of my second project from within the git source.

So I see two potential solutions to this problem.  One is to build an archive of the subproject and include that in the git build process, much like  you could include a jar file into a java project.  The subproject make file spits out a bunch of *.o and *.lo files and I don't know what to do with them :/

The other potential solution that I see is to include all the subproject source files into the git makefile and build it all at once.  This is the approach that I've taken so far but the problem that I'm running into is that the subproject files are missing their needed references to openssl and curl. :(  I've tried moving lines around and adding things to the git Makefile, but at 2600 lines, its not the easiest to understand or manipulate.

**Question**: how do I go about either editing the git makefile to build the subproject or creating an archive of the subproject object files for inclusion in the git build?

Comment: The monologue is nice, but what is your question?

Comment: just build the second project as a library. then link to it so you can call functions inside it (you will of course need to include the headers in your modified source)

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear.  I'm not very comfortable with makefiles, so I don't really know where to even start.

Comment: @SteveCox, how do I "build as a library"?

Comment: unfortunately you're gonna have to change the makefile to do that, unless they were nice and already put a target in for you. the -shared flag does this in gcc, but you're gonna need to learn a lot more about make before this is easy to do

Comment: forget what i just said, you have all of the .o files. you can easily just compile a shared lib with 'gcc [.o files] -shared -o lib.so'. but thats just a one time solution. you're gonna want to add a target to the makefile to do this for you